# Map binary combination array into binary index array

Tags: c#, loops, recursion

I've got a function wchich calculate next binary combination from previous one and would like to convert it into a function wchich calculate binary combination directly by loops. Binary array will be very big like million elements and even more. How to do that?

Combination function:

```
    void NextBinComb(byte[] b)
    {   
        byte c=1;
        for (int x = 0; x < b.Length; x++)
        {
            byte t = b[x] & c;
            b[x] ^= c;
            c = t;               
        }

        //print binary combination
        Print(b);
    }
```

This produces:

```
000000
100000
010000
110000
001000
101000
011000
111000
000100
100100
010100
110100
001100
101100
011100
111100
000010
100010
010010
110010
```

Into:

```
   //function that calculate binary combination directly by not using previous one
   void NextBinComb(k)
   {   
        byte[] b = new byte[k];
        int[] tab = new int[k];//indexes

        //these loops needs to create b array like function presented here on top
        //How to change them to achieve that goal?
        for (tab[0] = 0; tab[0] < n; tab[0]++)
            for (tab[1] = tab[0] + 1; tab[1] < n; tab[1]++)
                for (tab[2] = tab[1] + 1; tab[2] < n; tab[2]++)
                    for (tab[3] = tab[2] + 1; tab[3] < n; tab[3]++)
                        for (tab[4] = tab[3] + 1; tab[4] < n; tab[4]++)
                            ...
                            for (tab[k] = tab[k-1] + 1; tab[k] < n; tab[k]++)
                            {


                                //print combination
                                GetBinComb(tab,b);//Get binary combination 
                                Print(b);
                            }
    }

    void GetBinComb(int [] tab, byte [] b)
    {
            List<byte> list = new List<byte>();

            for (int x = 0; x < b.Length; x++)
            {

                  if (tab.Contains(x))
                  {
                        list.Add(1);
                  }
                  else
                  {
                        list.Add(0);
                  }
            }
            b=list.ToArray();
    }
```

Goal:

```
  byte[] GetCombinationBinaryIndexArray(byte[] binaryComb)
  {
        //sth

        return calculatedBinaryIndex;
  }
```

Usage:

GetCombinationBinaryIndexArray suppose to produce following indexes:

For 5 ones', n=8:

```
comb: 11111000  index: 000000
comb: 11110100  index: 100000
comb: 11110010  index: 010000
comb: 11110001  index: 110000
comb: 11101100  index: 001000
comb: 11101010  index: 101000
comb: 11101001  index: 011000
comb: 11100110  index: 111000
```

For 6 ones', n=8:

```
comb: 11111100  index: 00000
comb: 11111010  index: 10000
comb: 11111001  index: 01000
comb: 11110110  index: 11000
comb: 11110101  index: 00100
comb: 11110011  index: 10100
comb: 11101110  index: 01100
comb: 11101101  index: 11100
```

For 7 ones', n=8:

```
comb: 11111110  index: 000
comb: 11111101  index: 100
comb: 11111011  index: 010
comb: 11110111  index: 110
comb: 11101111  index: 001
comb: 11011111  index: 101
comb: 10111111  index: 011
comb: 01111111  index: 111
```

For 7 ones', n=12:

```
comb: 111111100000  index: 000000000
comb: 111111010000  index: 100000000
comb: 111111001000  index: 010000000
comb: 111111000100  index: 110000000
comb: 111111000010  index: 001000000
comb: 111111000001  index: 101000000
comb: 111110110000  index: 011000000
comb: 111110101000  index: 111000000
```

Comment: The `NextBinComb` function you described at the top is not recursive.

Comment: And where's the recursion? This looks like a terrible idea. What problem are you trying to solve, and what does it have to do with (co)recursion?

Comment: Recursive function can calculate next binary combination from previous one. I am looking a way to convert it into loops that are calculating binary combination directly. The goal is to map binary combination into binary index for huge arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you are doing, but NextBinComb() is a simple adder (adds 1 in this case). Only the bit-ordering is reversed. If you need to speed up the function you can break the for-statement when c gets 0.

Comment: Yes, that's adder. But how to achieve the same by many loops?

Comment: I fail to understand how this answers the question. Although I do admit that I have a hard time finding what the question is. However, the title says "convert recursive functions into loops" which this answer does not adress.

Comment: Can you write your goal again in a formula and not in C#? Because your C# codes does not run and misses information to help you, e.g. what its 'n' in NextBinComb()

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't understand. You write "GetCombinationBinaryIndexArray suppose to produce following indexes:" and that "index" is in all your examples always 0..7 in binary representation with reversed bit order. 000zzzzz 100zzzzz 010zzzzz ... 111zzzzz.

Comment: Ok, now I seem to understand your goal. You have an 8-bit field and want to distribute 8-5=3 zeros, 8-6=2 zeros and 8-7=1 zero in your field. And then your example lists the first 8 results.

Comment: No, It can be array with 2000 bits and 1780 ones or 1555000 bits and 780000 ones.

Answer (score 0):

i created this with Java but i think you can use the process for C#:

```
public void getNextBinary(boolean[] b, int position){
        if(b[position]  && b.length < position){
            getNextBinary(b, position + 1);
        } 
        b[position] = !b[position];
        if(position == 0){
            print(b);
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }

    void print(boolean[] b){
        for (int x = 0; x < b.length; x++)
        {
            if(b[x]){
                System.out.print("1");
            }else{
                System.out.print("0");
             }

        }
    }
```

And you can call it as follows:

```
boolean[] b = new boolean[]{false, false, false, false, false, false};
                Test test = new Test();
                for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
                    test.getNextBinary(b, 0);
                }
```

Comment: That's not the answer.